# Preg Match All doesn't Allow echo first character for Wordpress Taxonomy Tags

Tags: plugins, php, posts, taxonomy, regex

I have been working on a code, that finds particular words from my content and converts them to wordpress Taxonomy Tags. I want to prefix them with a '#' symbol... But somehow it doesn't work

This is the code:

```
 preg_match_all('/ #([A-Za-z\/\.]*) /', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); 
if(isset($matches[1])){ 
foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){ 
    $HashTag= $matchKey;
wp_set_post_tags( $ID, '#'.$HashTag, true); 
}
```

The issue is in the second last line of the code...

```
wp_set_post_tags( $ID, '#'.$HashTag, true);
```

I put a # symbol behind my text when setting post tags... But when the code executes the # is ommited and only $HashTag is echoed....

I tried to see if the issue is with something else so i tried using other words and alphabets other than '#'

```
wp_set_post_tags( $ID, 'ABC'.$HashTag, true);
```

It worked perfectly and had ABC behind each of my tags. I tried to do it with single alphabet and yet again it worked.

```
wp_set_post_tags( $ID, 'Z'.$HashTag, true);
```

But still I fail to do the trick with '#' symbol, so please help me out...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: It looks like term names are sanitized internally. Could you go through [`sanitize_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_term_field/) and check if one of those filters removes the #?

Comment: Hey there, i have no knowledge of how sanitize_term_field works... But may i tell you i tried this `'ab#'.$HashTag` basically adding 2 alphabets before the hash, and suprisingly  it worked. It had presevered the # along with 2 alphabets in the output...

Comment: I can't test this right now, sorry. Check the source code of the method I linked, there are a couple of `apply_filter('...', $var)` calls there. You can try these out inside your own code, my guess is that one of those strips special characters from beginning and end

Comment: When you add a tag via the standard admin page (for managing tags), does `#example` and `ex#ample` both work? But as kero pointed, there could be a code (in a plugin or the active theme) which is stripping the `#` when put at the start of the tag name.

Comment: Okay, So i am not good at code... I assumed that if wordpress cuts first few characters, i added few spaces before it but that didn't work. I honestly couldn't understand how to tackle the sanitize thing...  Things didn't work... I tried to str_replace() to change space with hashtag.... And it didn't work too...

Comment: What about trying the HTML entity for the '#' symbol, which is &#35; so your code would be: wp_set_post_tags( $ID, '&#35;'.$HashTag, true);

Comment: I tried and sorry to say that it didn't work...... Putting it in ' ' makes it show &#35 in the output rather than the actual '#''